# Using zsh autocompletion for alias

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, alias, oh-my-zsh

I have created a few aliases for git in `zsh`. For example: `gch` = `git checkout`, `grb` = `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date` and some more complex useful `zsh` functions for `git` commands. But how can I allow these aliases to use `zsh` `git` autocompletion?

Comment: What happens when you remove oh-my-zsh and instead just `zsh -f` and then `autoload -U compinit` and then `compinit` and then create the aliases?

Comment: My advise is to replace shell aliases like `gch`, with Git aliases like `g ch`. This way you get completion for free; in addition, it works for other shells like Bash, Fish, and PowerShell.

Answer (score 14):

I've had the same issue. You should check whether the option `completealiases` is set. It prevents aliases from being internally substituted before completion is attempted. In my case, removing `setopt completealiases` from my **.zshrc** resolved the issue. You can try `unsetopt completealiases` if *oh-my-zsh* sets it.

Comment: This also fixed `git-together`, which works by aliasing `git` to its own command.

Answer (score 5):

If you open the file which contains the autoloaded function defintion for `git` completion:
On my ubuntu system, its:

```
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git
```

at the top of the file you will see the `#compdef` declaration

```
#compdef git git-cvsserver git-receive-pack git-upload-archive git-upload-pack git-shell gitk tig
```

you can try adding your aliases to the `#compdef` definition, e.g.

```
#compdef git git-cvsserver git-receive-pack [...] tig gch grb
                                                      ^^^ ^^^
```

Then starting a new shell to get that new directive loaded.
Then try invoking completion.

#### What is `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`?

Its the file that contains the autoloaded "function" defining the completion behaviour for the all the commands defined in the `#compdef` directive, in this case the `git` family of commands, it lives in `fpath` and is autoloaded by compinit when the completion system is initialized.

#### What is `#compdef` ?

from `man zshcompsys`

> #compdef name ... [ -{p|P} pattern ... [ -N name ... ] ]
>                 The file will be made autoloadable and the function defined  in  it
>                 will  be  called when completing names, each of which is either the
>                 name of a command whose arguments are to be completed or one  of  a
>                 number of special contexts in the form -context- described below.

Comment: Is there a nicer way to make this happen so it can fit into my dotfiles?

Comment: yes there are other ways to script this out but did this work for you? I guess there is no point bothering with improving on this solution if it fundamentally didnt work in the first place.

Comment: Just tried it and no dice. I apologize for rushing into things.

Comment: @patrick oh ok sorry. it works for me with functions, however I dont use aliases anymore so I couldnt test on my system

Answer (score 4):

Piling up on [the_velour_frog's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335201/215257), if you don't want to modify the original completion file. You can use `compdef` directly:

```bash
compdef <completion_function> <function>
```

For instance

```bash
compdef _git gch
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar. Are you using oh-my-zsh? If so, make sure you've enabled the zsh-completions plugin in your `.zshrc` file. I'd also recommend the zsh-autosuggestions plugin.

Once you've done that, you'll need to add the following to your `.zshrc` file (if it's not already there)

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completions $fpath)
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

Comment: Yes, I am oh-my-zsh and I also already have that in the zshrc.